# Show that the lub of a set of negative numbers cannot be positive

Tags: sequences-and-series, supremum-and-infimum

How is this conclusion?

If a set $S$ contains only negative numbers then $0$ by definition is an upper bound. Any positive number would be greater than $0$ therefore, the lub of set $S$ can never be positive.

Comment: Correct so works

Comment: Correct indeed.